# What's wrong with this piece of code for saving contacts?

Tags: qt, symbian, nokia, contacts, qt-mobility

I am using the latest Nokia Qt SDK.
I have tried to add the contacts, it's not getting added.. what is missing here?

```
  // Construct contact manager for default contact backend
    QContactManager* cm = new QContactManager("simulator");
  // QContactManager* cm = new QContactManager("memory"); // i tried this, its also not working
  // Create example contact
    QContact example;
  // Add contact name
    QContactName name;
    name.setFirstName("John");
    name.setLastName("Doe");
    example.saveDetail(&name);

    // Add contact email address

    //QContactEmailAddress email;
   // email.setContexts(QContactDetail::ContextHome);
   //email.setEmailAddress(“john.doe@example.com”);
   // example.saveDetail(&email);
   // Finally, save the contact details
    cm->saveContact(&example);
    delete cm;
```

Thanks

Comment: I can't create the tag, but you should specify that you are using the Qt-Mobility API.  Are you following this documentation? http://doc.qt.nokia.com/qtmobility-1.0-tp/contacts.html

Answer (score 0):

`http://doc.qt.nokia.com/qtmobility-1.0-tp/qcontactmanager.html#availableManagers` check list of available managers, and use one of them. Maybe then it will work

Comment: ya, i am using them itself, but its getting crashed at the constructor only :(
available managers "symbian" is not working for N96 devices :(

Answer (score 0):

`cm->saveContact(&example)` returns `QList<QContactManager::Error>`. Are there any values return in this list?

-jk

Comment: Nope, its crashing while initializing the QContactManager, 
its crashing at constructor itself :(.
i tried for error code, not getting :(